# How to pass data from one app to another in android

Tags: android, android-intent

I have developed 2 apps, one for receiving data and displaying a list. Through this list I get   the data which I need to pass to another app to plot the data received by showing a Pie Chart.

Through my first app, the code snippet is below, I pass the data that is the double variable "pie" through Actionbar Click to open my second app.

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

```
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

case R.id.action_settings:
            if(item.isChecked()) item.setChecked(false);
            else item.setChecked(true);
            Intent i;
            PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
            try {
                i = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.example.piechartexample");
                if (i == null)
                    throw new PackageManager.NameNotFoundException();
                i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
                i.setAction("android.intent.action.MAIN");
                i.putExtra("Send", pie );
                startActivity(i);
            } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {

            }
            return true;
default: x="";Log.d(TAG, x);
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

This opens my second app piechartexample. But I am not able to get the value of pie to my second app. Code snippet of my second app below

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity { 

private  double[] VALUES =getIntent().getDoubleArrayExtra("Send"); 

// some other variables 
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.pie_chart_main);
// show pie char using achartengine
}
}
```

the error from logcat is

```
D/AndroidRuntime(21366): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm(21366): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41624ba8)
E/AndroidRuntime(21366): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(21366): Process: com.example.piechartexample, PID: 21366
E/AndroidRuntime(21366): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.piechartexample/com.example.piechartexample.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(21366):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
E/AndroidRuntime(21366):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
E/AndroidRuntime(21366):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
E/AndroidRuntime(21366):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
E/AndroidRuntime(21366):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
E/AndroidRuntime(21366):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
E/AndroidRuntime(21366):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
E/AndroidRuntime(21366):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(21366):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
E/AndroidRuntime(21366):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
E/AndroidRuntime(21366):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
E/AndroidRuntime(21366):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(21366): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(21366):    at com.example.piechartexample.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:30)
E/AndroidRuntime(21366):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(21366):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
E/AndroidRuntime(21366):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
E/AndroidRuntime(21366):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2101)
E/AndroidRuntime(21366):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: you want to send data from one activity to another or from one application to another??

Comment: I need to send from one application to another

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to just call `Intent.getStringExtra ("Send");` in the next activity. I assumed that `pie` is a `string` in this case.

Call that `getdoubleArrayExtra()` in the `onCreate(Bundle savedInstance)` method like

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
// some other variables 
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.pie_chart_main);
    private  double[] VALUES =getIntent().getDoubleArrayExtra("Send"); 
    // show pie char using achartengine
}
}
```

Comment: pie is not string but a double array..
public double pie[]={// some values"", "",""}

Comment: Ok then try "getIntent().getExtras().getDoubleArray("Send");"

Comment: Tried, but still I dont get the value of pie. Error on Logcat is unable to start activity of the second app.

Comment: This is how I have declared the intent within my activity in OnCreate in my second app.  

private  double[] VALUES =getIntent().getDoubleArrayExtra("Send");

Comment: The app crashes. The errors I get are "Unable to instantiate activity" and "null pointer exception" since the variable VALUES is empty

Comment: can you edit your question to include the code from your first activity as well as your second?

Answer (score 1):

In the receiving activity:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
String send;

if (extras != null) {
    send = extras.getString("Send");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

well if you want to send data from one app to another you can use content provider.
the following links may help you.Try this and reply if it works

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_content_providers.htm

Comment: Since my app is not that complicated, is there a way to achieve this through intents? Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi Anirudh, I did check the developer page, but the logic I have implemented in the question is more or less the same. From my first app I create an intent to my second app to pass the double value "pie". The first app works fine. But when I try clicking the button and open the second app, it fails and I get the error which I have posted.